# C++, When getting values from a list that I populate the arrays inside are returning nothing

Tags: c++, arrays, linux, linked-list, prims-algorithm

Okay so for a project in my algorithms class I'm suppose to, read from a .txt file all points in a disneyland map then use prims algorithm to solve the MST problem.

My issue is that I parse the values from the file into a temp array using a ' ' delimeter  then push them into a list. Everything is working fine and dandy until pushing the array onto the list then when receiving the value later in the program its not returning any values. i know its something silly but hopefully you all can help.

my code: http://pastebin.com/rS6VJ6iJ

disneyland.txt: http://pastebin.com/f78D0qrF

```
Output:
//testing arrays' value before pushing into list

    id: 1 ,x: 957 ,y: 685 ,name: RailRoadMainStreet
    id: 2 ,x: 1009 ,y: 593 ,name: MainStreetCinema
    id: 3 ,x: 930 ,y: 661 ,name: FireEngine
    id: 4 ,x: 991 ,y: 665 ,name: HorseDrawnStreetcars
    id: 5 ,x: 945 ,y: 673 ,name: HorselessCarriage
    id: 6 ,x: 1038 ,y: 668 ,name: Omnibus
    id: 7 ,x: 1062 ,y: 670 ,name: DisneyGallery
    id: 8 ,x: 1063 ,y: 649 ,name: GreatMomentsWithMrLincoln
    id: 9 ,x: 969 ,y: 562 ,name: BlueRibbonBakery
    id: 10 ,x: 968 ,y: 579 ,name: CarnationCafe
    ... to 84 id

//now retreving values from list after been pushed(empty)
id:  ,x:  ,y:  ,name: 
id:  ,x:  ,y:  ,name: 
id:  ,x:  ,y:  ,name: 
id:  ,x:  ,y:  ,name: 
id:  ,x:  ,y:  ,name: 
id:  ,x:  ,y:  ,name: 
id:  ,x:  ,y:  ,name: 
id:  ,x:  ,y:  ,name: 
id:  ,x:  ,y:  ,name: 
id:  ,x:  ,y:  ,name: 
id:  ,x:  ,y:  ,name: 
id:  ,x:  ,y:  ,name: 
id:  ,x:  ,y:  ,name: 
id:  ,x:  ,y:  ,name: 
id:  ,x:  ,y:  ,name: 
id:  ,x:  ,y:  ,name: 
id:  ,x:  ,y:  ,name: 
... to 84 id
```

i know this is something silly, but I just can't figure it out at the moment.

edit:

now im getting jibberish because the program is reading a blank line at the end for the file which i do not want to be read because there are no values
jibberish:
id: 84���   ����1222����422)����TomorrowlandTerrace���  ��ӿ���  ��

updated part of code that is causing errors:

```
if (data.is_open())
 {
    while (!data.eof()) 
    {

        getline(data,output);

        if (counter == 0) //grabbing the total amount of vertcies
        {
            total = atoi(output.c_str());
        }else if(counter == total+1){
            //no nothing , blank line. THIS IS CAUSING ERRORS
        }
        else{ // now parsing line into an array then pushing it into the remaining list.


                infoVert = new string[4];
                temp = parseLine(infoVert,output,' ');
                tmpVert.push_front(temp);



    }
        counter++;

    }
}

//---------------------
//cleaning up the mess.
data.close();
delete [] infoVert;
//---------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are deleting the array you've added to the list

```
string* parseLine(string* ary,string line,char delim)
{
    ...
    return ary;
}

infoVert = new string[4];
getline(data,output);
temp = parseLine(infoVert,output,' ');
cout << "id: " << temp[0] << " ,x: " << temp[1] << " ,y: " << temp[2] << " ,name: " << temp[3] << endl;
rVert.push_front(temp);
delete [] infoVert;
```

Look at `parseLine` the way that it written means `temp == infoVert`, so actually you are pushing `infoVert` onto your list, but on the next line you delete `infoVert`.

You could just not `delete[] infoVert` but really you should have a list of vectors instead of a list of pointers.

```
list<vector<string> > rVert;
list<vector<string> > tVert;
```

Programming is easier without using pointers.

Comment: nice! thank you; yeah i was considering vectors from the get-go, but its an algorithm class, thus efficiency in terms of big-o matters, arrays are less bloated.

Comment: No difference at all in terms of big-O between arrays and vectors.